# Como enviar o mostrar valores de un input creado de forma dinamica

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código en el cual me crea `inputs` de forma dinámica cada vez que pulso el botón. El problema es que no puedo hacer que muestre la información de todos los `inputs` que yo creo, solo puedo mostrar la información de uno de ellos.

Al pulsar el botón `Muestra los datos`, éste devuelve `undefined`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejemplo de HTML </title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ImprimeDatos(){                
            var resultado = "Nombre: ";                                 
                var correow = document.formaDatos.textcorreo.value;
                    resultado = resultado + ' ' + correow;  
                var fila1 = document.formaDatos.c1.value;
                    resultado = resultado + ' ' + fila1;

                    document.write('<p>Correo: '+ correow + '</p> <BR>');
                    document.write('<p>fila: '+ fila1 + '</p> <BR>');

                    //document.write('<a href="mailto:' + correow + '?body=' + fila1 + '">Enviar mensaje de correo </a>');   
        }

        function agregar_fila() {
            var tabla = document.getElementById("factura");    
            var fila = tabla.insertRow();    
            var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
            var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);

            var campo1 = document.createElement("input");
                campo1.type = "text";
                campo1.name = "c1";
                campo1.setAttribute("onclick","vaciar_campo(this);");
                campo1.style.height = "15px";
                campo1.style.width = "25px";        

            var campo2 = document.createElement("input");
                campo2.type = "button";
                campo2.value = "-";
                campo2.onclick = function() {

                    var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                    var tbody = tabla.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

                    tbody.removeChild(fila);

                }
            celda1.appendChild(campo1);
            celda2.appendChild(campo2); 
        }
        function vaciar_campo(input) {

            input.value = "";

        }   
    </script>   
    <body>
    <h1>Ejemplo de formulario con uso de JavaScript</h1>


        <form name = "formaDatos">


            <p>Email   <input name="textcorreo" size="30"/></p>

            <table id="factura" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1"> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>        
                    <th><input type="button" value="+" onclick="agregar_fila();"></th> 
                </tr> 
            </table>

            <button type="button" onclick="ImprimeDatos()">Muestra los datos</button>
            <button type="reset">Lipiar Campos</button>
        </form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ponle ID único a los nuevos elementos que añades al DOM (no sólo un name) y luego consulta su contenido por ID.

Comment: No veo muy claro el sentido de tu código, pero sí mucha mala práctica, como el hecho de usar funciones inline dentro de los HTML, es mejor que uses *listeners* asignando las funciones desde Javascript. En cuanto al código, ten en cuenta que si das el mismo `name` a varios elementos dentro del formulario, se va creando un array y luego tendrás que usar índices para encontrar los elementos específicos. Si en tu form por ejemplo hay dos `inputs` con `c1` como  `name`, y haces un `console.log(document.formaDatos.c1);` ...

Comment: ... vas a obtener algo como esto: `"0": <input name="c1" value="a"></input>,
  "1": <input name="c1" value="b"></input>,` y para acceder a cada valor tendrías que hacer algo así: `document.formaDatos.c1[0].value` para el primero, y  `document.formaDatos.c1[1].value` para el segundo. Yo creo que convendría que organices mejor tu código, que apliques buenas prácticas y si no encuentras salida podremos echarte una mano, pero debes explicar la lógica del programa en ese caso.